# Accessing nested data properties in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, template

I am using HandlebarsJS for my templating needs.

I have a nested object:

```
{
    "amount": {
        "preTax": 15.99,
        "tax": 0.0,
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "total": 15.99
    }
}
```

And I have the following template:

```
{{#amount}}
<div>PreTax is {{preTax}}. Tax is {{tax}}. Currency Code is {{currencyCode}} and total is {{total}}</div>
{{/amount}}
```

Is this the best practice for accessing nested properties within a property? Like declaring the `block` for the data property or I need to use `with`?

Like so:

```
{{#with amount}}
<div>PreTax is {{preTax}}. Tax is {{tax}}. Currency Code is {{currencyCode}} and total is {{total}}</div>
{{/with}}
```

I know that both approaches work. And in mustache-js I always used the former approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin Decker (one of the contributors Handlebars on Github) answered on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1029) I had created.

---

> The `with` form will be slightly faster than the generic block form due
>   to some optimizations that can be made for known cases like that. You
>   also have the option of making pathed lookups, `{{amount.preTax}}` for
>   example. All work and unless you have extremely hot code I wouldn't
>   worry too much about the performance of one vs. the other and leave to
>   to which feels stylistically the best for you.

So I guess there is no real winner, unless as Kevin points out, you have an extremely used template then `with` might be a better option.